# Congratulations, Bill!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

Only a short while after returning, he has broken the 100k!

Thanks for your answers, and congratulations, [Bill](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque)!

Comment: Anyway: $$\rm A\, hearty\, and\, well-earned\, congratulations\, Bill!\ $$ I appreciated so much your answering style: $$\rm \ \ n=3k\!-\!2\!:\ {\rm mod}\,\ \color{#0a0}{d_1:\ a^3\equiv b^2},\, b^3\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^3b^n\! = \color{#0a0}{a^3} b^{3k-2} \equiv (b^3)^k \equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,  f_n \equiv 0$$

Comment: I've deleted the comments about downvotes since such comments tend to become discussions about a users merit that do not really belong on a celebration thread.

Comment: [$$\text{Guess who's back? Back again. Bill is back, tell a friend.}$$](http://youtu.be/YVkUvmDQ3HY?t=33s)

I'm glad he's back. I've even made a [silly souvenir.](http://imgur.com/upbP4cA)

Comment: @GustavoBandeira: OMG, that's gold. :)

Comment: Thanks! Congratulations and thanks to *everyone* for their efforts in helping to make MSE the best general-level math forum on the web.

Answer (score 18):

After having been away for a year, and upon return, to work this hard on answering questions means there can be one and only one possible answer to this question:

Bill Dubuque is a unique individual who is a truly dedicated mathematics educator.

Thank you for all your hard work.

Comment: Finally, someone, posted a kind answer. :)